# Froala Error in Image Upload. Not showing the image in the froala editor

Tags: node.js, angular, froala

Im working with Angular6 and when I upload an Image with Froala I got this error in the Froala Editor:

> Something went wrong. Please try again.

[errorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZAfW.png)

My server-side code its ok, the image gets uploaded, and I get the JSON response with the right url.

My code:

```
    //component.ts:

    public options: Object = {
    charCounterCount: true,


    // Set the image upload URL.
    imageUploadURL: 'http://localhost:3000/upload_image',

    // Additional upload params.
    imageUploadParams: {id: 'my_editor'},

    // Set request type.
    imageUploadMethod: 'POST',


  };
```

---

```
    //component.html

    <div class="row">
      <div [froalaEditor]="options" [(froalaModel)]="contenidoTema"></div>
    </div>
```

---

```
//server-side code
//app.js

var FroalaEditor = require('wysiwyg-editor-node-sdk/lib/froalaEditor.js');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../bower_components')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Path to upload image.
app.post('/upload_image', function (req, res) {

  // Store image.
  FroalaEditor.Image.upload(req, '/uploads/', function(err, data) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
    // Return data.
    if (err) {
      return res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
    console.log("http://localhost:3000"+data.link);
    res.send("http://localhost:3000"+data.link);
  });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure if you will get a valid json response here `res.send("http://localhost:3000"+data.link);`

Comment: you will have to send the `res.send({ link : "http://localhost:3000"+data.link });`

Comment: OMG, so simple, that solved my issue. Thanks a lot ! :)